# not show image in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel5.2 but after using this code:

```
{!! Html::image(asset('/images/t1.png'),'',['class'=>'img-rounded']) !!}
```

The image is not shown.

[image]

Comment: try `asset('/dist/images`

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
{!! Html::image(asset('/dist/images/t1.png'), '', ['class'=>'img-rounded']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{!! Html::image(url('/dist/images/t1.png'),'',['class'=>'img-rounded']) !!}
```

or

```
{!! Html::image(URL::asset('/dist/images/t1.png'),'',['class'=>'img-rounded']) !!}
```